# Iterator confusion need clarification

Tags: java, iterator

Just need a quick clarification:

While using the iterator class, can I create a iterator object like below:

Option1: `<Class-name>Iterator [Iterator-object] = <object-name>.iterator();`

or should i be sticking to

Option2: `Iterator<Class-name> [Iterator-object] = <object-name>.iterator();`

Can you briefly explain why the suggested one is correct?

Comment: The first option is not a legal syntax.

Comment: First is illegal syntax. It's just a convention: it was decided to be like this. Could be option 1, but I think that would give the compiler a little more work. Also what benefit you see in the first option?

Comment: Can you post some concrete example?

Comment: The proper syntax is `Iterator<ClassName> itr = obj.iterator();`, not `<ClassName>Iterator itr = obj.iterator();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Iterator<T> iter = someObject.iterator()` is correct.

But if `someObject` is `Iterable` (like, for example, a `java.util.List`) and all you need to do is actually iterator over it, use a 'for-each' loop:

```
for(T thing : someObject) { /* do stuff with 'thing' */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Option 2. As syntactically correct Java, it will enable your program to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29)?

> `Iterator<E> iterator()`
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

all depends on what you exaclty wanted to itrate either a ArrayList/List or any other collection of string /object.
eg you wanted to itrate on a ArrayList then you take 
ArrayList al =(you data );
Itrator itr=al.itrator ();
also you can view how to use itrators for help http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=125